# Zend framework redirect back to form if validations fails

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

Zend Framework 1.7. Using a restful controller. Implemented `newAction` and `postAction`. 
In `postAction` when data validations fail I want to redirect back and I want to view the form populated with the params (and the errors messages).

```
//controller
public function newAction() {
    $form = new My_Form_form ();
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

public function postAction() {
        $newData = $this->getRequest ()->getPost ();

        $filters = array();
        $validators = array (
                'name' => array (
                        'presence' => 'required' 
                ) 
        );

        $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
        $input->setData($newData);
        if (!$input->isValid()) {
            $this->_helper->redirector ( 'new', 'controller' );
        }
    }
```

On submit the form redirect to `PostAction`. The redirect don't save the current params so the form is not populated with the previous data. 
What is the better way to do the correct redirection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the post inside the newAction so something like this:

```
//controller
public function newAction() {
   $form = new My_Form_form ();


    $newData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

if(!empty($newData){
    $filters = array();
    $validators = array (
        'name' => array (
            'presence' => 'required' 
        ) 
    );

    $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
    $input->setData($newData);
}

$this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: no, I am using http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest

Comment: ok, but you have to populate the form to have the values and errors with the data you get on your post. If you want to have it in 2 separated methods is fine too, as long as you populate the form before it is send to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't set the Filters and Validators in the Form Class and use two Actions?

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html

This code should help you.

```
public function newAction()
{
    //init the form
    $this->view->form = $form = new Your_Form();

    if($this->_request->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();

        if($form->isValid($formData)) {
            //get form data with filters
            $data = $form->getValues();

            //do something


            //redirect
            $this->_helper->redirector("index");
        }  else {
            /* Form Error */
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Becouse if I recive a post from a non-web application (like smartphone) I don't need a form. So the validations must be isolated to rest of the form.

Comment: Ah ok, use: $this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module, $params); Use $formData as $params. In the newAction you get the params with $this->_getParam($paramName); or as Array with $this->_getAllParams();

Comment: If the validation fails I want to redirect with the errors messages